# Flask - render template asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask

I'm making a Flask app and I was wondering if I could render a template for a route, but redirect the user after a function is complete. Currently using Python 2.7 Here is my example

```
@app.route('/loading/matched')
def match():
    time_match()
    return render_template('matched.html')

def time_match():
    # match two users based on time
    sleep(3) # pretend to be doing
    return redirect('/loading/generation')
```

I don't know where to begin. Is there a library I should use?

Comment: You can't send headers (which are headed for a redirect) after you've started sending back the response body (i.e., the rendered template).

Comment: Looking back this this now — stupid af.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like a client sided thing to me? Do you want something like a loading bar?

You could provide an ajax route which initiates heavy workload on the server side - while the client does show some progress. Once the workload finished you render a template which than gets loaded via ajax.

For asycn workload you could look into [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html), which is a great library for that. It even can do work on a seperate server...

More sources [Integration in Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/celery/)

Comment: [Nice tutorial for Async with Flask and Celery](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Hannes! Basically, on this route, I make several requests to the Spotify API. It takes about 10 seconds for the API to finish and return a playlist. I wanted to render a view while making those requests

Comment: So the requests to Spotify dont have any impact on the renderd Template? You just want to get rid of the delay on the user-side?

Comment: Yes, Hannes. The template will just be a loading animation. I've read a bit more and it seems like I'll want to use multiprocessing. When the requests are finished, the browser should navigate to the next page/route. To handle the navigation, I think I'll have to use Flask-SSE. The function will just send a notification when the requests are complete and then the client will just navigate to the next page while passing whatever data I need to the next route.

Comment: SSE seems like a nice solution - i wasnt aware of that :)

Celery would have worked too - depending of the amount of clients to be handled it is simply overkill.

If you expect high traffic on that service it could be a good idea, since you can route the CPU-Intense stuff on a seperate server while you maintain a responsive frontend.